# SharePoint 2010 Save ListItem without closing

Tags: development, javascript, list-item

Is it possible to save a ListItem without closing the modal dialog in SharePoint 2010? Possibly by replacing the save button on the Ribbon with a custom button that calls the submit function and keeps the window open?

Basically, trying to add a custom button that will save the item and then run some additional code but not close the item's modal dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use a custom editform, and include use of Client object model or SPServices to do the save action itself within the form. Clicking the 'Save' button in the ribbon will close the window, no way round that really.

Another method (which I'd probably do) is build a custom application page that has an update panel that does the logic of doing whatever I need to do, and launch that within a dialog box from a custom ribbon action or ECB action or whatever.

Comment: Was hoping to get by with adding the button to the ribbon -- rather than modifying the editform.aspx. So, I want my button to prompt the user to save the item before it'll run my custom code. Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 1):

A solution to the "Save without closing" is using Infopath, setting in the expanded send options to "leave the form open"

[image]